# Error using lambda in java aspect

Tags: java, lambda, annotations, aop, aspectj

We have a custom annotation:

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AsyncWithTimeout {
   long timeout();
}
```

And a custom `@aspect` which intercepts the methods annotated with `@AsyncWithTimeout` as follows, **working fine** (note the task definition, without lambda)

```
@Aspect
public class AsyncWithTimeoutInterceptor {

   @Around(value = "@within(com.foo.AsyncWithTimeout) || " + "@annotation(com.foo.AsyncWithTimeout)")
   public Object asyncWithTimeout(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {  
     long timeout = ((MethodSignature) point.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(AsyncWithTimeout.class).timeout()

     // Task without lambda -> OK
     Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
        public Object call() {
           try {
              // Do some stuff with the timeout...
           } catch (Throwable throwable) {
              // Do some stuff...
           }
        }
     };

     // Do some stuff ...
   }
}
```

However, if we use a lambda instead to initialize task, an **Exception** is thrown:

```
@Aspect
public class AsyncWithTimeoutInterceptor {

   @Around(value = "@within(com.foo.AsyncWithTimeout) || " + "@annotation(com.foo.AsyncWithTimeout)")
   public Object asyncWithTimeout(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {  
     long timeout = ((MethodSignature) point.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(AsyncWithTimeout.class).timeout()

     // Task with lambda -> Error
     Callable<Object> task = () -> {
        try {
           // Do some stuff with the timeout...
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
           // Do some stuff...
        }
     };

     // Do some stuff ...
   }
}
```

Exception detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: there is no classname for invokedynamic
        at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.InvokeDynamic.getClassName(InvokeDynamic.java:126)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAccessForInlineMunger.openAroundAdvice(BcelAccessForInlineMunger.java:141)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAccessForInlineMunger.munge(BcelAccessForInlineMunger.java:80)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:441)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:101)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1689)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1633)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1398)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1155)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:527)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:363)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:121)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
```

> **EDIT**: Actually aspectjweaver version is 1.8.0

Versions used: jdk 1.8.0_124, aspectjweaver 1̶.̶9̶.̶1̶  1.8.0

File `aop.xml` in my META-INF:

```
<aspectj>
   <aspects>
      <aspect name="com.foo.AsyncWithTimeoutInterceptor"/>
   </aspects>

   <weaver>
      <include within="com.foo.*"/>
   </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Should I be able to use lambdas in aspects or there is some kind of limitation/bug?
Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a bugentry on some AspectJ tracker, but still: interesting observation!

Comment: Thanks for comment @GhostCat! You were absolutely right. I made a mistake in my question and the aspecjweaver version used was 1.8.0 actaually 1.8.0 instead 1.9.1. I've just checked that the error is solved in 1.9.1 version :/

Comment: @troig in this case, you can simply either remove the question, or answer it yourself

Comment: Done @Eugene! I prefer to keep the question, maybe can help other people using old aspectjweaver versions. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I made a mistake in my question and the aspectjweaver version used was actually **1.8.0** instead of **1.9.1**.

> ***EDIT***: As @kriegaex points in a comment, the bug is already solved in 
>    the 1.8.13 aspectjweaver version (not necessary upgrading to 1.9.1)
>   Thanks for pointing out.

I've just checked that the error is solved in version **1.8.13** and later, so lambdas can be used in aspects without problems.

Comment: Why did you use 1.8.0 and not the latest 1.8 version 1.8.13? There were many bugfixes during the 1.8 series of releases, also upstream in the Eclipse compiler which is the basis for the (forked-off, but regularly refreshed) AspectJ compiler. Chances are that it would work, I see no need to use the brandnew 1.9.1 version which mainly supports Java 9 and partly Java 10.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex!thanks for the comment. To be honest, I’m not sure why we did use 1.8.0 version. It was in our production servers since long time ago. When the bug of the question appeared, my first idea was trying with the latest 1.9.1. Anyway, I’ll follow your suggestion and I’ll try upgrading to 1.8.3. Maybe will be enough...Thanks again!

Comment: Attention, that was 1.8.13, not 1.8.3.

Comment: @kriegaex you were right, the bug is already fixed in 1.8.13. I've edited my original answer. Thanks